# Override AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

Is possible to override the default AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan for a specific ticket on a custom OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider? The default expiration time for all other tickets is 15 minutes.

```
public public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    ...
    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, properties);

    if (condition)
    {
        ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(14);
    }

    context.Validated(ticket);
}
```

The generated token with condition == true has the default expiration time (15 minutes). I would like to not change the context.Options.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan because it affects all tokens and that's not the idea.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to set the expiration time in the `TokenEndPoint` method instead of `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method:

```
public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
{
    ...

    if (condition)
    {
        context.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(14);
    }

    ...
}
```

I hope it helps.

**EDIT**

As pointed by [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2835914/michael) in his [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36610641/2054754) to a similar question, if you have a different `AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan` for each client_id you can override the default configured `AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan` in the context options with the client one when validating the client authentication:

```
public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
{
    ...

    context.Options.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(client.AccessTokenExpireTime);

    ...
}
```

Comment: It changes: expires_in, but doesnt change .expires

Answer (score 2):

This works in the context (ha ha) you have:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
     context.Options.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = YourCustomExpiryTimeHere();
}
```

But note, will need to be updated on every call or the last value you assign will be kept for the next login that occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```
public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
// Note: a= how much time u want
    Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(a);
}
```

also have many different option like:

FromDays,FromHours,FromMilliseconds,FromMinutes