# ASP.Net MVC Extend OAuth Token Expiration

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to extend the access token expiration from ASP.Net. Below is the code from App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            //AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(364), 
            AllowInsecureHttp = true // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
        };
```

However, the token was not last for a year if I deployed to live site. I used postman to test, managed to get the token, but the token would be expired after 20minutes.

Providers/ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs

```
public ApplicationOAuthProvider(string publicClientId)
    {
        if (publicClientId == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("publicClientId");
        }

        _publicClientId = publicClientId;
    }
```

Result from Postman

```
{
"access_token": "accesstoken",
"token_type": "bearer",
"expires_in": 86399,
"userName": "admin@admin",
".issued": "Thu, 11 Oct 2018 04:39:03 GMT",
".expires": "Fri, 12 Oct 2018 04:39:03 GMT"
}
```

Is there anything I can do to extend in the ASP.Net MVC way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OWIN Security - How to Implement OAuth2 Refresh Tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637674/owin-security-how-to-implement-oauth2-refresh-tokens)

Comment: I think the proper question here is why `AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(364)` is not working, instead it is using the default 20 minutes token expiration.

Comment: could u plz add your `ApplicationOAuthProvider`

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado I tried with different timespan, unfortunately all are not working. FromDays, FromMinutes...... all would be expired by 20min.

Comment: @ershoaib updated

Comment: @hahahaha, you have to implement `ApplicationOAuthProvider `s `override` method to working as intended.

Comment: @ershoaib what do you mean? I'm using OAuthOptions, isn't it?

Comment: @ershoaib i've updated the question, with postman result. im able to get the expires after 1 day (im using 1 day now), but it doenst work.

Comment: what changes you made in code for 1day?

Comment: This Q is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701398/oauth2-webapi-token-expiration