# OWIN AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan override

Tags: owin, access-token

I'm attempting to override access token expiry time dynamically (on a client-by client-basis), per the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120754/override-accesstokenexpiretimespan). Upon overriding the expiry time in ValidateClientAuthentication, the "expires_in" field does not show in the response anymore.

Can anyone clarify why that may be and how to get it back?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My bad.

I had an invalid value set for the value of ExpiresUTC.