# Setting token lifetime for different grant types in identityserver4

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

Is it possible to set the token lifetime for different grant types in identityserver4.

**Example: Can I can set lifetime with password grant to 20 mins and set lifetime with my extension grant to 10 mins?**

Comment: You can set this for each client individually.

Comment: Please see my response to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32150404/2054754) where you can see two different ways to override the AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan.

Comment: Thanks @jumuro . Can you share little more details about the implementation.

Comment: @Satyajit, it seems that IdentityServer4 doesn't use OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider, sorry for the mistake. I'm afraid I don't know how to do what you want with IdentityServer4.